# Segmentation fault when inserting struct into a map

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault, stdmap

The `mapBase` parameter being populated will represent a coordinate system. I use `std::map` to easily order coordinates based on x and then pair to a y coordinate that is ordered by an inner map. The value of the inner map will hold extra information later. For now it is populated with dummy data.

I'm attempting to insert a struct into a `std::map`, but get a segfault on the insertion. The segfault is not always consistent. Sometimes the insertion will work a number of times, and then segfault after no particular set of times.

I have tried adding debug statements that tell me when something was successfully inserted by using the result of the `std::map::insert` function and looking at the second field of the result. This was only helpful when a segfault did not occur and was generally always true since I clear the `mapBase` at the start of the called function. I have also tried using smart shared pointers as the final value type of the `baseMap` instead of just the struct object itself. This did not change my outcome. I also tried allocating `*(new cell())` with the same result. I have provided the basic code below.

main:

```
    #include <map>
    #include <cmath>
    #define DEG_TO_RAD(deg) deg * M_PI / 180

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
      // vector of lidar range, angle pairs
      std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> lidarData {{0.585, -179.41},
                                                        {0.689, -151.672},
                                                        {0.671, 56.6557},
                                                        {0.717, 122.164},
                                                        {0.611, 159.344},
                                                        {0.586, 175.279}};
    
      // convert returns to x, y coordinate point
      std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>> points;
      for(const auto& beam : lidarData)
      {
        double angle = DEG_TO_RAD(beam.second);
        double range = beam.first;
        double x = range * cos(angle); // r * cos(theta)
        double y = range * sin(angle); // r * sin(theta)
        Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> point;
        point << x, y;
        points.emplace_back(point);
      }
    
      auto* newA = new A();
      newA->doSomething(points);
      
      return 0;
    }
```

Header:

```
class A {
    public:
        A();

        ~A();
  
        void doSomething(std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>> &points);
  
    private:
        struct cell {
            Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> mean;
            Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2> covariance;
            std::vector<double> x_m {};
            std::vector<double> y_m {};
            std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>> hits {};

            cell();
        };

        // define a map keyed by a x coordinate with a value of  std::map.
        // inner map is keyed by a y coordinate with a value of struct type cell.
        typedef std::map<double, std::map<double, cell>> map;
        map mapBase;
    }
}
```

Source

```
A::A() {}

A::~A() {}

void A::doSomething(std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>> &points) {
    mapBase.clear();
    for (const auto &point : points) {
        auto x = point.x();
        auto y = point.y();

        auto xIt = mapBase.find(x);
        if (xIt == mapBase.end()) { // coordinate does not exist if true
            std::map<double , cell> yPair;
            yPair.insert(std::make_pair(y, cell()));  // Segfault happens here
            mapBase.insert(std::make_pair(x, yPair));
        } else { // x exist in map, but check if y does
            auto yIt = mapBase.at(x).find(y);
            if (yIt == mapBase.at(x).end()) { // y does not exist at x if true
                mapBase.at(x).insert(std::make_pair(y, cell()));
            }
        }

        // Emplace values at the new cell in the map. 
        mapBase.at(x).at(y).x_m.emplace_back(x);
        mapBase.at(x).at(y).y_m.emplace_back(y);
        mapBase.at(x).at(y).hits.emplace_back(Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>());
        mapBase.at(x).at(y).mean.setOnes();
        mapBase.at(x).at(y).covariance.setOnes();
    }
};

A::cell::cell() {
    mean.setZero();
    covariance.setOnes();
    x_m.clear();
    y_m.clear();
    hits.clear();
}
```

On regular execution of the code I just get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) at the insertion of the struct. Using gdb, the back trace is as follows:

```
#0  std::pair<double const, cell>::pair<double, A::cell, true> (__p=..., this=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:362
#1  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<double const, A::cell> > >::construct<std::pair<double const, A::cell>, std::pair<double, A::cell> > (this=<optimized out>, __p=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136
#2  std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<double const, A::cell> > > >::construct<std::pair<double const, A::cell>, std::pair<double, A::cell> > (__a=..., __p=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:475
#3  std::_Rb_tree<double, std::pair<double const, A::cell>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<double const, A::cell> >, std::less<double>, std::allocator<std::pair<double const, A::cell> > >::_M_construct_node<std::pair<double, A::cell> > (this=0x7fffffffd6d0, __node=0x55555585ed90) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:626
#4  std::_Rb_tree<double, std::pair<double const, A::cell>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<double const, A::cell> >, std::less<double>, std::allocator<std::pair<double const, A::cell> > > >::_M_create_node<std::pair<double, A::cell> > (this=0x7fffffffd6d0) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:643
#5  std::_Rb_tree<double, std::pair<double const, A::cell>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<double const, A::cell> > > std::less<double>, std::allocator<std::pair<double const, A::cell> > >::_M_emplace_unique<std::pair<double, A::cell> > (this=this@entry=0x7fffffffd6d0) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:2351
#6  0x0000555555596ddd in std::map<double, A::cell, std::less<double>, std::allocator<std::pair<double const, A::cell> > >::emplace<std::pair<double, A::cell> > (this=0x7fffffffd6d0) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:569
#7  A::doSomething (this=this@entry=0x5555558082d0, points=std::vector with 49 elements = {...}) at ...
```

The backtrace did not make obvious the issue, but further debugging has shown that removing the mean and covariance from the struct allows the application to run without faulting. I could just separate them into separate parameters, but that is not really the correct solution in my opinion. Maybe in the copy invocation when making a pair causes the issue and handling of Eigen parameters are mismanaged? Any help in the understanding and solution to my issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you also provide `main.cpp` so that we can have a [minimal reporducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is `ndtMapBase`?

Comment: I added a minimally runable main application function per request and removed the ndtMapBase since it did not belong. I have narrowed down the issue to the Eigen matrices in the cell struct. Removing them allows the application to run without issue,  but not e solution I'm going for.

Comment: @notARobot I have tried your given code. And it did not produce any segmentation fault with gcc 7.5.0 . Which compiler(with version) are you using? I even ran it in the debugger multiple times and it exited normally. I wanted to get segmentation fault so i can see what is causing it. But i could not get the segmentation fault with gcc 7.5.0 although you have written that `yPair.insert(/*with arguments here*/);` produces the seg fault.

Comment: @AnoopRana, Thank you for trying my code. Here is the compiler version gotten when checking in the terminal.

gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0

So, same version as you. It is odd you do not have the issue on your machine. I wonder if it is because of the limited size in data in the example. I get my data from an actual lidar rather than an initialized vector as I provided. So there are many more samples. Also, I use mean and covariance in latter code. In your case, the compiler may have optimized those parameters out for you since they are not used in the example.

Comment: @notARobot I have corrected 1 or 2 mistakes in your program and pasted it as an answer. Check it out and do tell me if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some mistakes in your above given code snippet which i have removed. The program works now without giving segmentation fault. You could try this and confirm me of the same.

**mainneweighen.cpp**

```
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include "neweigen.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
      std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> lidarData {{0.585, -179.41},
                                                        {0.689, -151.672},
                                                        {0.671, 56.6557},
                                                        {0.717, 122.164},
                                                        {0.611, 159.344},
                                                        {0.586, 175.279}};
    
    
      std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>> points;
      for(const auto& beam : lidarData)
      {
        double x = beam.first * cos(beam.second); // r * cos(theta)
        double y = beam.first * sin(beam.second); // r * sin(theta)
        Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> point;
        point << x, y;
        points.emplace_back(point);
      }
    
      auto* newA = new A();
      newA->doSomething(points);
      
      return 0;
    }
```

**neweigen.cpp**

```
#include "neweigen.h"

A::A() {}

A::~A() {}

void A::doSomething(std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>> &points) {
    mapBase.clear();
    for (const auto &point : points) {
        auto x = point.x();
        auto y = point.y();

        auto xIt = mapBase.find(x);
        if (xIt == mapBase.end()) { // coordinate does not exist if true
            std::map<double , cell> yPair;
            yPair.insert(std::make_pair(y, cell()));  // Segfault happens here
            mapBase.insert(std::make_pair(x, yPair));
        } else { // x exist in map, but check if y does
            auto yIt = mapBase.at(x).find(y);
            if (yIt == mapBase.at(x).end()) { // y does not exist at x if true
                mapBase.at(x).insert(std::make_pair(y, cell()));
            }
        }

        // Emplace values at the new cell in the map. 
        mapBase.at(x).at(y).x_m.emplace_back(x);
        mapBase.at(x).at(y).y_m.emplace_back(y);
        mapBase.at(x).at(y).hits.emplace_back(Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>());
    }
}

A::cell::cell() {
    mean.setZero();
    covariance.setOnes();
    x_m.clear();
    y_m.clear();
    hits.clear();
}
```

**neweigen.h**

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <map>
class A {
    public:
        A();

        ~A();
  
        void doSomething(std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>> &points);
  
    private:
        struct cell {
            Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> mean;
            Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2> covariance;
            std::vector<double> x_m {};
            std::vector<double> y_m {};
            std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>> hits {};

            cell();
        };

        // define a map keyed by a x coordinate with a value of  std::map.
        // inner map is keyed by a y coordinate with a value of struct type cell.
        typedef std::map<double, std::map<double, cell>> map;
        map mapBase;
    };


#endif
```

The above three files work without giving any segmentation fault.

Comment: I copy and pasted the above files in a new projects and ran the application. I get the same segfault in the same location. I added debug statements before and after the insert of yPair as std::cout << "Before Insert" << std::endl; std::cout << "After Insert" << std::endl; respectfully. The application then worked. I saw all messages and no segfaults. Not sure why adding std::cout would fix the issue unless there is an initialization issue.

Comment: I fixed the errors in the originally posted code. Mostly copy errors when trying to remove irrelevant code for the post so not to bog down other users with unnecessary code bits.

Comment: @notARobot That's strange specially because i am using the exact same compiler(and version). My gcc version output is exactly the same as yours. That is i have the output as: `gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0`. I am also using Ubuntu 18.04 with gcc 7.5.0 .

Comment: @notARobot When you compiled the above three files(that i have given) are you also compiling some other source files besides these in your project? If you're compiling some other files(besides the above 3) then maybe the cause is from those other files. Can you try compiling these exact 3 files and see if it produces seg fault.

Comment: Also, just to ensure that the Eigen matrices are not optimized out, I added mapBase.at(x).at(y).mean.setOnes();
mapBase.at(x).at(y).covariance.setOnes();
With these, even with the std::cout outputs, the application segfaults.

Comment: @notARobot If you're compiling some other files(besides the above 3) then maybe the cause is from those other files. Can you try compiling these exact 3 files and see if it produces seg fault. And yeah using `.at()` is better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define first the types of the pair:
`std::pair<double,cell> new_pair = makepair(y,cell)` and then insert it into the map.

Comment: I did try your suggestion, but did not get a different result. The issue is certainly related to having the Eigen objects for mean and covariance inside the struct. Removing them allows the application to run without faults. I just don't have the full understanding why this is the case however.